# Shell script in ~/bin working, but command not found

Tags: bash, scripts

This is probably a stupid question, so sorry for wasting your time here, but i have run into a problem while creating a shell script.
The script itself does run (for testing purposes it's just an echo), however i want it to run from just its name by placing it in the ~/bin/ folder. This has worked for me in the past, but i seem to have made some kind of mistake.
Console outputs:

```
johannes@pickle:~$ ~/bin/d
hahaha
johannes@pickle:~$ d
d: command not found
```

the script I'm using:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo hahaha
```

EDIT: rebooting solved it. thank you to dessert for that tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `~/bin` directory is added to your PATH by the following lines in `~/.profile`:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

This tests whether the directory exists and adds it, but `~/.profile` is only run on login – thus, if you just create `~/bin` it is not added to your path before the next login/reboot. You can add it manually by running:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is located in `~/bin/d`, it is a local directory (`/home/<user>/bin`).

It is not added to PATH, so it won't work without a path to the file.